Install nvidia-legacy-300xx-driver on Debian Bookworm
Recently I've tried to follow a video of the "Linux gaming experience", because I want to  completely switch from Windows, which I use only for gaming, to Debian, which is installed with Windows in dual boot.
Following the Wiki NvidiaGraphicsDrivers, I run nvidia-detect to check which driver to install for my NVidia card, and nvidia-detect just tells me my card can support only 300xx legacy driver.
There is the problem, because with Debian 12 Bookworm apparently they removed the apt packet nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver because of a bug (there is no package available for bookworm nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver.
The most quoted solution is add into apt file the repository for sid (unstable version of Debian) or for bullseye and download the legacy driver from here. I think this is not a "good solution" because I'm installing a packet removed for a bug problem (and not actually a "minor problem"...) and I am actually breaking Debian stable.
What is the best solution to install NVidia drivers for old video cards? Would Debian bullseye be better than Debian bookworm for gaming? Or  should I prefer OS like Fedora for gaming, maybe in dual boot with Debian?
Note: I've also seen Debian bookworm comes with nouveau and optimus installed (in case you have a IGPU and a video card), but I can't understand if optimus just uses internal video card (Intel) or uses nvidia card or both by default. Is optimus with Nouveau the best alternative to nvidia driver? Or nvidia-driver is just the best option for optimal performance?


You can't install the proprietary driver because that old version is not compatible with newer kernels since many years ago. 2. You have to use nouveau and 3. nouveau is for Nvidia ONLY!!


Hi @ChanganAuto, thanks for reply. I ask for some clarifications: 1. What do you mean for "that old version?". I tried installing that legacy driver following the link Supported NVIDIA. Scrolling down, there is a section for supported GPU and says "The 340.xx driver supports the following set of GPUs:". 2. Is it the best alternative? I tried running low performance games and it's very laggy (Tboi with no DLC) 3. Sorry my bad, I meant optimus, I've updated the post


non sequitur... The problem ISN'T the kernel, it's the driver not being updated to support newer kernels. 2. Again, nouveau is driver from now on and indeed it never performed like the proprietary driver except for very old chipsets (performance for those is a moot point anyway, obviously). 3. Again, nouveau is an alternative, unofficial, community driven driver for NVIDIA graphics, whether standalone or in hybrid setups is irrelevant.  In a nutshell, your hardware is de facto obsolete, in Linux OR Windows.


@ChanganAuto got it. If u post the answer, I close the question. Greetings
